# Return a List sorted by FirstName?

Tags: linq

Given this:

```
public static List<DoctorFullName> GetListDoctorsNames()
  {
  using (var db = new WaitListDataContext())
  {
     return db.Doctors.Select(c => new DoctorFullName()
      {
        FullName = c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName,
        DoctorId = c.DoctorId
      }).ToList();
  }
}
```

How do can I return the list sorted by FirstName?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add an `.OrderBy()` clause.  You can sort by only the `FirstName` before your `.Select()`:

```
return db.Doctors
         .OrderBy(c => c.FirstName)
         .Select(c => new DoctorFullName()
  {
    FullName = c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName,
    DoctorId = c.DoctorId
  }).ToList();
```

Or you can sort it after your `.Select()`, since your new field begins with the `FirstName` value anyway:

```
return db.Doctors.Select(c => new DoctorFullName()
  {
    FullName = c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName,
    DoctorId = c.DoctorId
  })
  .OrderBy(c => c.FullName)
  .ToList();
```

[The `IEnumerable<T>` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) provides a lot of methods for manipulating a collection and returning the modified collection, so they can be chained together in lots of different ways.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static List<DoctorFullName> GetListDoctorsNames()
  {
  using (var db = new WaitListDataContext())
  {
     return db.Doctors.OrderBy(doc => doc.FirstName).Select(c => new DoctorFullName()
      {
        FullName = c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName,
        DoctorId = c.DoctorId
      }).ToList();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that's it! I will award the Answer as soon as allowed. Can you explain, "doc => doc.FirstName)"? I'm new to C# and Linq to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do an ordering:

```
public static List<DoctorFullName> GetListDoctorsNames()
  {
  using (var db = new WaitListDataContext())
  {    
     return db.Doctors
              .OrderBy(d => d.FirstName)
              .Select(c => new DoctorFullName()
                  {
                    FullName = c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName,
                    DoctorId = c.DoctorId
                  })
              .ToList();
  }
}
```